# Ads script: errors when create keywords CONCURRENT_MODIFICATION without any modification

Tags: google-ads-api

I have a script which copy ads, keywords, negativeKeywords, sitelinks, callouts, shippets from master account to slave account
Everything works properly. But when I create keywords in slave account I receive errors
[CONCURRENT_MODIFICATION : DatabaseError.CONCURRENT_MODIFICATION : ]

Most weird that from 10 execution of script 5 can be executed without any error but 5 with error

```
  function copyKeywords(slaveGroup, masterKeywordsData, replicationSettings) {
var count = Object.keys(masterKeywordsData).length;
l('Copying %s keywords...', count);

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var key = Object.keys(masterKeywordsData)[i];
  var masterKeywordData = masterKeywordsData[key];
  log('%s/%s - Replicating keyword %s...', (parseInt(i) + 1), count, masterKeywordData.id);
  log('Keyword data: %s', JSON.stringify(masterKeywordData));

  var slaveKeyword = null;
  var finalUrl = null;

  if(masterKeywordData.finalUrl) {
    finalUrl = formateUrl(masterKeywordData.finalUrl, replicationSettings);
  }

  slaveKeyword = slaveGroup
    .newKeywordBuilder()
    .withText(masterKeywordData.text);

  if(finalUrl) {
    slaveKeyword = slaveKeyword
      .withFinalUrl(finalUrl);
  }

  slaveKeyword = slaveKeyword
    .build();

  if (slaveKeyword == null) {
    log('Nothing was replicated');
  } else {
    if (slaveKeyword.isSuccessful()) {
      log('Keyword %s successfuly replicated', masterKeywordData.id);
    } else {
      log(slaveKeyword.getErrors());
      error('Cannot replicate keyword %s ', masterKeywordData.id);
    }
  }
  sleep(2000);
}
```

}

With 2000 milliseconds sleep I receive errors not so often. But sometimes it happens(
Does anybody know why I receive error about 
[CONCURRENT_MODIFICATION : DatabaseError.CONCURRENT_MODIFICATION : ]
cause I do not make any modification